# Testing component with custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I've stucked when learning how to tests react components with custom hooks. I think that the issue is connected with hook mocking but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm using jest and react-testing-library.

counter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import useCounter from 'hooks/useCounter/useCounter';

const Counter = props => {
  const {count, increment} = useCounter();

  return (
    <div>
      Counter: <span data-testid='counter-value'>{count}</span>
      <button onClick={increment} data-testid='increment'>+1</button>
    </div>
  );
};


export default Counter;
```

useCounter.js

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);

  return {count, increment};
}
```

counter.test.js

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import Counter from './counter';

describe('counter.js', () => {
  const mockIncrement = jest.fn();

  jest.mock('hooks/useCounter/useCounter', () => {
    return jest.fn(() => ({
      count: 0,
      increment: mockIncrement,
    }))
  })

  it('should call counter increment', () => {
    render(<Counter/>);
    const buttonElement = screen.getByTestId('increment');
    fireEvent.click(buttonElement);

    expect(mockIncrement).toBeCalled();
  })
})
```

Error message:

```
  ● counter.js › should call counter increment

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

Comment: Are you trying to test the custom hook, or are you trying to test your component? If testing the hook, that should be done in isolation. If testing the component then click the button and assert the displayed count was incremented.

Comment: I'm trying to test component which use custom hook for increasing counter value. I thought that I need to mock this hook in test file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mock the hook during the test. You want your test to resemble the actual behaviour as closely as possible.

In this case, just click on the button and check if the count value has been updated to the expected value in the DOM.

```js
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import Counter from './counter';

describe('counter.js', () => {
    it('should increment count value on click', () => {
        render(<Counter/>);
        fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: '+1' }));
        expect(screen.getByTestId('counter-value')).toHaveTextContent('1');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After few days of test learning I'm sure that trainer from online course that I attended was unprepared...